# How do I use an array as a key in a Google Apps Scripts dictionary and have it maintain its array structure while I iterate over the dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, google-apps-script

Why do the square brackets of the array get taken away when I use the array as a key? Looking at this function and the output vs expected output, how do I make sure the key is actually an array and that I can index it as such?

```
function functionName() {
  d = {};
  a = [3, 3];
  d[a] = 100;
  Logger.log(d);
  //output: {3,3=100.0}
  //expected output: {[3,3]=100.0}
  for (var key in d){
    Logger.log(key);
    //output: 3,3
    //expected output: [3, 3]
    Logger.log(d[key]);
    //output: 100.0

    //I would like to be able to say
    //index1 = key[0];
    //index2 = key[1];
    //where index1 and index2 will evaluate to 3
    //but this throws an error
  }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Objects only allow strings as keys. Use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead:

```js
function functionName() {
  d = new Map();
  a = [3, 3];
  d.set(a,100);
  console.log([...d]);//expected output: {[3,3]=100.0}
  d.forEach((value, key)=>console.info({key,value}))
}
functionName();
```